# Removing outline on image map area

Tags: html

Is there anyway to remove the outline when you select an area on an image map? See: 
[image]

I'm using Chrome on Snow Leopard.

Comment: See here for cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12196766/1491212

Comment: Thanks Armel, Sorry I didn't come back to this sooner.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It seems like all you got to do to remove these borders lies on the `img` tag, by setting the `hidefocus` attribute and the `outline` css property on it like this:

HTML

```
<img class="map" src="..." usemap="..." hidefocus="true" />
```

CSS

```
img.map, map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

This should work cross-browser!

**EDIT**

Like Sergey K commented, if you're not looking to support IE6 you can save bytes by just using an attribute selector.

```
img[usemap], map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

[Support starts with IE7.](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2)

Comment: Any way to get it to work in IE with pure CSS, i.e. without the `hidefocus="true"` part? Tried up to IE11, no luck so far.

Comment: I guess not... don't you have access to sourcecode? Javascript?

Comment: Of course, 'hidefocus' is not valid a valid attribute in HTML5.

Comment: +100 for providing an answer in 2012 that works for IE6

Answer (score 8):

I was having this same issue with both chrome and safari and found success by assigning a class .map to each area tag and giving the class the following style:

```
.map {
outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Kinda old-fashioned, but
does this work:

```
    <area onfocus="blur();" ...
```

?

GTX, CS

Comment: I tried many many (border, outline, ..) things, and only this worked, thanks.

Comment: Working with SharePoint 2013 and this was the only technique that worked.  Thanks

Comment: causes dotted outline in Firefox, removing that and adding a tabindex="-1" to each <area> solved it for me.

Comment: It worked for me but I needed to apply this only to IE, because otherwise Firefox showed the dotted border while the area was clicked (before releasing the click)

Answer (score 6):

Give your imagemap an id of "Map" then use the following CSS declaration:

```
#Map area {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, cause the area tags inherits the outline from the image you've "added" the map tag to. So, to be sure, I've added the "outline: none;" property not only to the area tags, but to the main image too.

Answer (score 2):

So if you have an archaic webpage without css (I know awful!) you can fix it by inserting
style="outline:none" after the coords and before the href within the area tag- absolute perfection!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS.  Set `style="outline:none;"` on the element, or preferably, put it in a style sheet.

Comment: On what element? Putting on the area tag doesn't do it. Neither when putting it on the image tag.

Comment: @meow I believe you want to put it on the `area` elements of the image map but if you're saying that doesn't work, then I'm really not sure.  Double check there aren't any spelling/syntax mistakes... we all make them.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `outline:0` on its css rule ?

Comment: Any idea how to remove the semi-transparent box that appears on Safari for iOS?