# html images maps: how to not have a border when clicking a selectable part of image

Tags: html

Sorry for the awkwardly phrased question. But I've made a website who's menu consists of an image map and when clicking a certain part of the menu a blue border appears around the coordinates. Is it possible for me to get rid of the blue border?

I can't upload an image cause I lack the reputation but if you'd like a reference image I could directly send you one.

edit: added code

```
        <div id = "logo"><img src="./images/logo.png" usemap="#menu"></div>    

        <map name="menu">
            <area shape ="rect" coords="0,131,331,0" href="index.html">
            <area shape="rect" coords="5,156,60,132" href="film.html">
            <area shape="rect" coords="60,156,118,132" href="photo.html">
            <area shape="rect" coords="118,156,216,132" href="illustrations.html" >
            <area shape="rect" coords="216,156,270,132" href="misc.html" >
            <area shape="rect" coords="270,156,323,132" href="about.html" >

        </map>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
[how to remove the border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478049/how-to-remove-the-border)

```
area:focus{
  border: none;
  outline-style: none; 
  -moz-outline-style:none;  
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ub886/6/

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property that causes you to see that blue outline is called `outline`

In your `.css` file or inside `<style> </style>` at the top of your `.html` add:

`input {
    outline: 0;
}`

And to take care of any other exceptions you might have:

`input:hover, input:active, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}`

Also, this will work only for the `<input>` tag. Change `input` in the css to whatever your tag is

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I've tried to apply this to the img property, the map property and to a div where I've contained all the info for the image map. Any idea what is up? Also, this only happens on Chrome and Safari, not Firefox so it might be a browser specific attribute I need to edit.

Comment: @EvanLuc Can you add the HTML code to your question so I can get a better view of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

apply this css property to image

`outline:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [Removing outline on image map area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821724/removing-outline-on-image-map-area) :

CSS

```
img.map, map area{
    outline: none;
}
```