# how to remove the border?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

please help to solve the problem.

html:

```
<img class="logo_pic img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" usemap="#link_index" />

<map name="link_index">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1,1,400,480" href="index.html" alt="" />
</map>
```

the problem is that when you click on the image appears blue border in the image. they disappear in a second, but I need to make it not appear

http://jsfiddle.net/Ub886/1/

google chrome last version

Comment: to put it tersely, `<img style="border:0" ...` will do it. I advise you to do this in a stylesheet, however.

Comment: Takes me right back to onfocus=this.blur days of IE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue border you are seeing is actually a hyperlink in "active" state. You can add css definitions to style those borders:

```
area:focus{
  border: none;
  outline-style: none; 
  -moz-outline-style:none;  
}
```

[Fiddle as example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub886/6/)

Comment: Bear in mind that the `:focus` styles should give some visual indication of where the focus is for keyboard navigation, see: '[outlinenone](http://www.outlinenone.com/).'

Comment: Good point! One can also consider using `area:focus` for styling to remove the `:active` border only from image areas. (I'll add this to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img class="logo_pic img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" usemap="#link_index" style="border:0"/>
```

You could do this on the `CSS` stylesheet as well

```
.logo_pic img-responsive {
    border:0;
}

.logo_pic img-responsive:hover {
    border:0;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
img:active, :focus { outline: none; -moz-outline-style: none; }
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ub886/4/

Comment: What border are you talking about? Can you make an image pointing to it? I can't see the border

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS 
...

```
<img class="logo_pic img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="border:0;" usemap="#link_index" />

<map name="link_index">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1,1,400,480" href="index.html" alt="" />
</map>
```