# I cannot seem to git rid of dashed lines on area tags in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, cross-browser, imagemap

I would like to be able to click one of the area tags in the code below, without it showing dashed lines around that pertaining section. It only does it in Internet Explorer. It's really annoying and I've tried using the following css tricks

```
a:focus, a:active { outline: none; }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I even tried javascript, using an `onblur()` technique and a tab index attribute but this did not work either.

```
<map name="image-maps-2016-04-06-161450" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-04-06-161450">
    <area alt="/" tabindex="-1" href="@Url.Action("Progressive","Home",new {id = ""})" shape="rect" coords="0,0,956,383" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area alt="/" tabindex="-1" title="" href="@Url.Action("SingleVision","Home",new {id = ""})" @Global.SingleVision shape="rect" coords="967,0,1916,384" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area alt="/" tabindex="-1" title="" href="@Url.Action("New_Media_Optics","Home",new {id = ""})" @Global.NewMediaOptics shape="rect" coords="1926,0,2872,384" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area alt="/" tabindex="-1" title="" href="@Url.Action("Kids", "Home", new { id = "" }) " @Global.NavKids shape="rect" coords="2882,0,3831,382" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="1918,190,1920,192" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="" />
</map>
```

Can anyone please let me know what I can do to make these dashed lines go away. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821724/removing-outline-on-image-map-area/12196766#12196766

Comment: Wow! Thanks man. I really appreciate it @Rion Williams